# How to use mysqli_insert_id with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, auto-increment

I have the following code and I'm getting crazy with calling an auto_increment id

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (x1, x2) VALUES(?,?)";
if($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
$query->bind_param('ss', $x1, $x2);
$query->execute();

$id = mysqli_insert_id($query);
```

For a reason I don't know why this is not working. I also tried

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($sql);
```

And

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id();
```

I just decided to work with mysqli. Before that, I only used MySQL where I had no problem with

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: did you check your db connection?

Comment: yes. thats all fine. it is working well. the query will executed into db. i just need that id for mkdir().

Comment: Look: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like

```
$query->commit(); OR $query->close();
```

Comment: hello, no when i use commit it will show Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::commit()

Comment: when close: Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in

Answer (score 3):

You must pass the mysqli *link* to `mysqli_insert_id()`, not the query:

```
$link   = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$sql    = "INSERT INTO tablename (x1, x2) VALUES(?,?)"
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$id     = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

or since you were using object oriented style:

```
// ...
$id     = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to stick to OOP style. It will cause you less confusion. In OOP style you only need to access a property on the object. For example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $x1, $x2);
$stmt->execute();
// Either one will work
$stmt->insert_id;
$db->insert_id;
```

If you want to use the procedural mysqli style then you have to remember that there are two functions. One if for the `mysqli` object and the other is for `mysqli_stmt` object. You need to pick either one of them, but you have to pass the right object to it.

```
// For mysqli_stmt object
mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);
// For mysqli object
mysqli_insert_id($db);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$result) {
        {
             die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

        } else {

        echo "<p>Done!.</p>";

        }
```

Try this and check the output...